# Having some code inside setInterval execute only once

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a `setInterval` call inside my Javascript which checks if there are new notifications for the user. This interval makes an AJAX call and updates the DOM based on the response. This interval is set to repeat every 10 seconds.

There is a little box that needs to popup if there are new notifications and it is inside this interval. In the current code, this box shows up every 10 seconds if there are new notifications that are not marked as *seen* and that's pretty annoying.

Is there a way to make this little box appear only once per notification set? So for example there are X new notification and after 10 seconds this number didn't change, don't show this box. How do I achieve this? I'm stuck here.

This is how my interval code looks like:

```
setInterval(function(){
    $.get(generate_site_url() + 'user.php?action=get_notifications', function(data) {

        response = $.parseJSON(data);

        if ('error' in response)
        {
            return; 
        }

        if (response.notification_array.length == 0)
        {
            return; 
        }

        $('.user-notification').text(response.notification_count);
        $('.no-notes').hide();

        var notificationStr = '';

        for (var key in response.notification_array) 
        {
            var notification = response.notification_array[key];
            var notificationHTML = '<li' + ((notification.notification_seen == false) ? ' style="background: #fffaf1;"' : '') + '>';
            notificationHTML += '<a href="' + notification.notification_target + '" id="nid-' + notification.notification_id + '">';
            notificationHTML += '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-' + ((notification.notification_type == 'like') ? 'thumbs-up' : (notification.notification_type == 'dislike') ? 'thumbs-down' : (notification.notification_type == 'favorite') ? 'heart' : 'bell') + '"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;';
            notificationHTML += notification.notification_message;
            notificationHTML += '</a></li>';

            notificationStr += notification.notification_message + '<br />';

            $('.notifications-dropdown').prepend($(notificationHTML));
        }

        display_alert(notificationStr, 'danger', 5000, 'bottom'); // This shows the box
    });
}, 10000);
```

Comment: `if (notificationStr.length > 0) display_alert(...);`?

Comment: You've answered your own question... store the count of "unseen" messages and compare every interval. If the new count is above the old, show the message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll expand my original comment answer here.

Set a variable accessible outside the interval function, in which you track the last count of new notifications. Next time the interval runs, compare the counts and check if there are any new ones.

```
var lastNewMessageCount = 0;
setInterval(function(){

  // ajax stuff
  if( response.notification_array.length > lastNewMessageCount ){
    // show notices

  }
  lastNewMessageCount = response.notification_array.length; 

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try making a global Array, then adding a conditional `if(response.notification_array.length > nameOfGlobalArray.length)` before the execution of `display_alert()` and update `nameOfGlobalArray` to match `response.notification_array` if the conditional returns true, like:

```
var notificationsArray = [];
setInterval(function(){
    $.get(generate_site_url() + 'user.php?action=get_notifications', function(data) {

        response = $.parseJSON(data);

        if ('error' in response)
        {
            return; 
        }

        if (response.notification_array.length == 0)
        {
            return; 
        }

        $('.user-notification').text(response.notification_count);
        $('.no-notes').hide();

        var notificationStr = '';

        for (var key in response.notification_array) 
        {
            var notification = response.notification_array[key];
            var notificationHTML = '<li' + ((notification.notification_seen == false) ? ' style="background: #fffaf1;"' : '') + '>';
            notificationHTML += '<a href="' + notification.notification_target + '" id="nid-' + notification.notification_id + '">';
            notificationHTML += '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-' + ((notification.notification_type == 'like') ? 'thumbs-up' : (notification.notification_type == 'dislike') ? 'thumbs-down' : (notification.notification_type == 'favorite') ? 'heart' : 'bell') + '"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;';
            notificationHTML += notification.notification_message;
            notificationHTML += '</a></li>';

            notificationStr += notification.notification_message + '<br />';

            $('.notifications-dropdown').prepend($(notificationHTML));
        }

        if(response.notification_array.length > notificationsArray.length)
        {
            display_alert(notificationStr, 'danger', 5000, 'bottom');
            notificationsArray = response.notification_array;
        }
    });
}, 10000);
```

[EDIT] **BotskoNet**'s method uses less data, and apparently my brain wasn't turned on :P Both will work, though.

Comment: Comparing strings is too problematic, it requires building the string and comparing text - simply comparing the count of the messages would do and would avoid iterating the array

Answer (score 0):

Does user.php mark a notification as seen once it has been delivered? I will assume not, but if so you just need to check if new notifications came in and only call the `display_alert()` if so.

Keeping track of notification count or comparing string is not enough. There are plenty of use cases where this will result in false positives. But I see there is a `notification_id` field:

```
var delivered= [];
setInterval(function(){

  // ajax stuff
  for (var key in response.notification_array){
     var notification = response.notification_array[key];

     // check if the notification has been delivered
     if ($.inArray(notification.notification_id, delivered) === -1){ 
         // notification has not been delivered 
         delivered.push(notification.notification_id);

         // process notification as normal
     }
  }

  // only display the alert if there is something to display...
  if (notificationStr.length > 0) 
      display_alert(...);

}, 10000);
```